# Passing bitwise operation as argument to function in C

Tags: c

What will be the argument value if we call function with the following argument

```
void func((0x1 | 0x3))
```

Is it true that if the result of this operation is >0 it gives true, and for the opposite it gives false, or we get 0x3 as a return value of this operation?

Comment: `(0x1 | 0x3) == 0x3` so `0x3` (or just `3`) will be used surely?

Comment: @xing it depends on what the function expects as argument, bool (true or false) or for example int . So if it expects bool, I will get true from this operation and if expects int I will get 0x3. Also it depends on operator type: logical or bitwise as dasblinkenlight provided in his answer.

Comment: I added the c++ tag since it spawned an interesting discussion about differences between the 2 language cousins.

Comment: @chqrlie: Yes, now I've had to put some more meat in my answer.

Comment: What's `void func((0x1 | 0x3))`even supposed to mean? It is not valid syntax. And what do you mean "return value"? Return where? From a function returning `void`? Just... what? I have no idea what you are asking and I have no idea how the posted answers have any relevance to "Passing bitwise operation as argument to function in C".

Comment: That's not even related to parameters. It is a simple expression. Why did you not look it up yourself? What was unclear?

Comment: @Olaf Yes it is expression, but a result of it will be passed as argument to function. I think it is clear for what I am asking in main post.

Comment: @Lazar: Get a better C book. what you do with the result of the expression is **completely** irrelevant. If your problem is not related to the operator, provide a [mcve] and learn [ask].

Comment: @Olaf Ok, I will try to be more clear next time.

Comment: It would be better to do at least _some_ research before you ask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`0x1 | 0x3` is a compile-time evaluable constant expression: it's an `int` type with the value 3.

If you were thinking of the `||` operator, then in C, the value of `0x1 || 0x3` is an `int` type with the value 1 as evaluation of `||` stops at the first non-zero argument. This short-circuiting property also applies to C++ but here the type would be `bool` with the value `true` and you have to take extra care if `func` is overloaded<sup>1</sup>:

```
void func(int)
{
    // pay me a bonus
}

#ifdef __cplusplus
void func(const bool&)
{
    // reformat my hard disk
}
#endif
```

---

<sup>1</sup>C++ allows functions to be overloaded, C doesn't. Yet another important difference.

Comment: I've added that. A small but important difference between the two languages for the pub quiz.

Comment: @chqrlie C doesn't have a bool type, whereas C++ does, so in C it returns a truthy value whereas C++ actually returns `true`

Comment: @NickA: technically, C has a boolean type since C99, but the logical operators still evaluate to an `int` type.

Comment: @chqrlie: That's the one.

Comment: @chqrlie ahhh technicalities

Comment: The `||` operator has different semantics in Javascript, where the result has the type and value of the left operand if it evaluates to true and the type and value of the right operand otherwise. This is very useful and `gcc` has an extension with similar semantics: `x = y ?: z`;

Answer (score 3):

Since you used only one pipe, the result is bitwise OR, not a logical OR:

```
0x01 | 0x03  ---> 0x03
```

Logical OR uses two pipes:

```
0x01 || 0x03 ---> 1
```

Answer (score 0):

`|` is the bitwise operation so the result will be `3`

Answer (score 0):

From a boolean perspective, a value of 0 is false and any non-zero value is evaluated as true.

Because you're using the bitwise-OR operator `|`, the expression `(0x1 | 0x3)` has the value 0x3:

```
  00000001 = 0x1
| 00000011 = 0x3
----------
  00000011 = 0x3
```

If this value is passed to a function expecting a `_Bool` (or equivalently `bool`), it is converted as per section 6.3.1.2 of the [C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf):

> When any scalar value is converted to `_Bool`, the result is 0 if the
>   value compares equal to 0; otherwise, the result is 1.

If the function is expecting an `int`, the value is not converted.